# InfluxDB schema design - need only summation of thousands of time series data

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am very new to InfluxDB.

I am writing a program to monitor electricity usages from 13,000 homes' electric meters located in 11 districts. The data will be used for a reporting program that mostly cares only the total usages from the 11 districts. However, I am asked to store every single home's usage into InfluxDB.

Can I have one measurement that contains 13,000 series? This will make summation every easy (I guess) but will 13,000 be too many?

Can I have 13,000 measurements with each has 1 series? Will it be costly to do summation cross measurements?

Answer (score 0):

By default InfluxDB `max-series-per-database` configuration is set to one million, so 13k series is nothing. One measurements with many measurements will be better, also from the query perspective - you won't need to use regexp to sum data from 13k measurements:

```
SELECT SUM(<field_key>) FROM <regular_expression_measurement>
```

Check https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/hardware_sizing/ -> 13k series is low load.